# Como puedo usar std::basic_filebuf de <fstream> para escribir en un archivo en c++

Tags: c++, fstream

He estado buscando tanto en ingles como en español, y no consigo información que entienda al respecto; intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    basic_filebuf <char> * buferDeArchivoBasico;    //Quiero entender el uso de basic_filbuf.
    //ofstream * buferDeArchivoBasico;              //con este Sí funciona
    buferDeArchivoBasico->open("archivo.txt",ios_base::out);

    *buferDeArchivoBasico << "intento escribir esto en el archivo"; //Este es el problema

    buferDeArchivoBasico->close();
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

¿Para qué sirve `basic_filebuf`? y si es posible un ejemplo por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ ofrece diferentes abstracciones de lectura/escritura de datos, en general estas abstracciones se separan en [búferes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAfer_de_datos) (buffer) y flujos ([stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing))).

Existen matices conceptuales entre un búfer y un flujo, en general:

- Los búferes suelen ser un paso intermedio y temporal de un procesamiento posterior.
- Los flujos suelen ser una entrada directa y continua de datos.

En base a estos diferentes conceptos, la clase `basic_filebuf` ofrece utilidades para gestionar el búfer (avanzar, retroceder, sincronizar...).

> ¿Para qué sirve `basic_filebuf`?

Para empezar, no se espera que uses `std::basic_filebuf` directamente si no alguno de sus alias: `filebuf` con `char` como tipo subyacente o `wfilebuf` con `wchar_t` como tipo subyacente.

Su utilidad es tratar archivos (file) como búferes de datos, y por ello ofrece herramientas de lectura y escritura de datos en crudo pero carece de herramientas de lectura y escritura de datos con formato, para este tipo de utilidad seguramente estabas buscando `std::basic_fstream` que **si** ofrece el operador de inserción de datos ([`operator <<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)) del que `std::basic_filebuf` carece.

> ¿Puedes darme un ejemplo en código que utilice `filebuf`?

En la [documentación de Microsoft sobre `basic_filebuf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/tzf8k3z8.aspx) tienes un [Hex Dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) implementado con dicha clase. Pero si te parece un ejemplo muy complicado, te dejo un ejemplo de lectura y escritura:

```
template <typename T>
void escribir(T valor)
{
    std::cout << "Escribir " << valor << '\n';
    std::filebuf archivo;
    if (archivo.open("archivo.bin", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary))
    {
        archivo.sputn(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&valor), sizeof(valor));
    }
}

template <typename T>
void leer(T &valor)
{
    std::cout << "Leer sobre " << &valor;
    std::filebuf archivo;
    if (archivo.open("archivo.bin", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary))
    {
        archivo.sgetn(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&valor), sizeof(valor));
    }
    std::cout << " leido " << valor << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nqK36K1Qnyd4mHJL)</kbd>.

Comment: Puedes darme un ejemplo en código que utilize filebuf?

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Para qué sirve basic_filebuf?

`basic_filebuf` es un buffer de bajo nivel. De hecho está más bien pensada para ser una clase base para el desarrollo de interfaces de más alto nivel... como podemos ver, por ejemplo, [aquí](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00253.html).

Que sea de bajo nivel implica que su interfaz es bastante escueta y sin demasiadas facilidades... esas facilidades las van a proporcionar las clases que hereden de `basic_filebuf`.

En cuanto a tu código, nota que `buferDeArchivoBasico` es un puntero... **que no has inicializado!!!!**. Lo raro es que no te haya fallado aquí:

```
buferDeArchivoBasico->open("archivo.txt",ios_base::out);
```

Prueba a usar el objeto por valor... te aseguras su inicialización y te olvidas de liberar la memoria más adelante:

```
basic_filebuf <char> buferDeArchivoBasico;
buferDeArchivoBasico.open("archivo.txt",ios_base::out);

// ...

buferDeArchivoBasico.close();
```

Por otro lado, si revisamos la [documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) vemos que esta clase no tiene sobrecargado el operador de inserción. Podemos solucionarlo facilmente proporcionando nuestra propia sobrecarga:

```
template<class T>
basic_filebuf<T>& operator<<(basic_filebuf<T>& out, std::string const& str)
{
  out.sputn(str.c_str(),str.length());
  return out;
}
```

Y con esto tu código ya debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Intenté utilizar el ultimo código que escribiste, pero no lo pude hacer funcionar, podrías darme un ejemplo con un código completo para poder entender su uso en la practica?